# Oracle use variable in in SQL query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have something like this:

```
With a as (select id from table_a)
select * from table_b where table_b.id > (select min(id) from a)
```

table_a is a huge table with millions of records and I don't want to go through all the records to find the min(i) every time I want to use min(i). Is there any way for me to store the min(id) in a variable and use it in the query? Something like this :

```
With a as (select id from table_a),
b as ((select min(id) into min_id from a))
select * from table_b where table_b.id > min_id
```

Comment: Is the query plan telling you that Oracle is actually getting the min(id) from table_a for every row in table_b?  I would expect that the optimizer would know that it could scan `table_a` just once so I wouldn't expect there to be any benefit to rewriting the query.

Comment: Also you are declaring query inside with clause and naming it as `a`, but you are not using it

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be doing what you want.  But, if you really want to be sure, move the subquery to the `from` clause:

```
select b.*
from table_b b join
     (select min(id) as min_id from a) a
     on b.id > a.min_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may help Oracle by defining an index on the `table_a`on column `id` to *not go through all the records to find the min*.

If the index is defined, Oracle performs a single index access to get the minimal row.

Without the index, you'll hav eto perform one `FULL TABLE SCAN` of the large table.

The best way to verify is to observe the execution plan:

```
 create index idx_a on table_a(id);  

EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'q1' into   plan_table  FOR
With a as (select id from table_a)
select * from table_b 
where table_b.id > (select min(id) from a);
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'q1','ALL')); 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |         |  5524 | 71812 |    49   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLE_B |  5524 | 71812 |    47   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   SORT AGGREGATE            |         |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| IDX_A   |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("TABLE_B"."ID"> (SELECT MIN("ID") FROM "TABLE_A" "TABLE_A"))
```